# Display Details of dish when hovering over image ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, image, hover

I have a number of images on my page and I would like to have some kind of notes/Comment/details appearing next to it explaining what the image is for when they hover over any particular Image.

It is restaurant project. when some one hover on image it show dish text description.

How would I go about achieving that?

(I am after something similar to when you hover over the tags below on this stackoverflow page...)

```css
body 
{
}

/* Image Box Style */
#mainwrapper .box {
 border: 5px solid #fff;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 100px;
 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
}
#mainwrapper .box img {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out; 
 transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}

/* Caption Common Style */
#mainwrapper .box .caption {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 position: absolute;
 color: #fff;
 z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out; 
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
 left: 0;
}

/** Caption 3: Fade **/
#mainwrapper .box .fade-caption
{
 opacity: 0;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 0px;
}

/** Fade Caption :hover Behaviour **/
#mainwrapper .box:hover .fade-caption
{
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainwrapper">
    <div id="box-3" class="box">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" CssClass="dishimg" runat="server" Width="100px" Height="100px" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("Image","~/Images/{0}") %>' />
        <span class="caption fade-caption" >
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comment") %>'></asp:Label>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all, or are you expecting Stack Overflow to *do the work for you*?

Comment: I tried some thing but text over flows when the data gets more. previously i tried on image. but it wont work for me.

Comment: Show what you have tried on your question, and tell us what the expected output was, for us to see where it went wrong

Comment: update question with code @Jcl

Answer (score 0):

You can use title attribute in image tag. On mouseover the title will be displayed. For example:

```
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" title ='test'>
```

Comment: ya tried this also but my image size is small height 100:px  width:100px  but i want more text. as we can say small description of dish @qamar

Comment: Did u try using more text in title? How's that look like?

Comment: `<asp:Image ID="Image1" CssClass="dishimg" runat="server" Width="100px" Height="100px" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("mage","~/Images/{0}") %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("Com") %>'` If data gets more it not display, means if characters goes around 200

Comment: I have tried with very long title and it gets displayed when mouse over the image. Please take a look here : http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=RoHDQ9H32G